# Proper Way To Run MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am very new to PHP development, and I was wondering what is the proper way to execute a MySQLi query. Here are two things that I noticed from tutorials and resources online.

Basically this one stores everything in a variable;

```
//$con is a database connection
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM table");
```

Then this one stores the syntax then runs it using the mysqli_query() statement

```
$query = "SELECT* FROM table";
mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

When the code runs, will the first one still execute even if it's just stored in a variable?

Comment: `Basically this one stores everything in a variable;` - Yes ... and no. Not directly. It stores the result of the `mysqli_query` in the variable `$query`. Both examples work the exact same way. There's not really a difference between them. I'll recommend always the second one, because if you need to use your query a second time, you just can change that `$query` string once and you won't have to chance every singe query in each `mysqli_query` function.

Comment: ^ Well said. Regardless of syntax you will still have to fetch the results to use in whatever fashion you intend to use them.

Comment: *"When the code runs, will the first one still execute even if it's just stored in a variable?"* **A:** Only if there are no errors.

Comment: @Twinfriends thank you for the help, it makes sense now

Comment: Actually you won't have access to the result in the second one because you don't assign the result to a variable:  `$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);`

Answer (score 0):

Please visit:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php

mysqli_query()

> Returns FALSE on failure. For successful SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE or EXPLAIN queries mysqli_query() will return a mysqli_result object. For other successful > queries mysqli_query() will return TRUE.

You must save the return value of mysqli_query() in order to use the mysqli_result object or test if the sentence failed.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-result.php

So the proper way to to execute the code is:

```
//$con is a database connection
$query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT* FROM table");

if(!$query) {
    // iterate the variable
}
```